Radio Label Image with CSS Combinator to have "checked" function?
Codepen Link
I'm trying to transform the label image upon click to scale and have 100% opacity, but I can't figure out how to tag it properly given my current syntax.
I know .console input[type=radio]:checked is correct because it will show the border around the radio button. I've tried every combination of >, ~, and + I can think of, but I must be missing something obvious.
<div class="container">
  <label class="container-select">
    <img src="https://placehold.co/600x400">
    <input type="radio" name="field" id="field-1" value="1">
  </label>
    <label class="container-select">
    <img src="https://placehold.co/600x400">
    <input type="radio" name="field" id="field-2" value="2">
  </label>
    <label class="container-select">
    <img src="https://placehold.co/600x400">
    <input type="radio" name="field" id="field-3" value="3">
  </label>
    <label class="container-select">
    <img src="https://placehold.co/600x400">
    <input type="radio" name="field" id="field-4" value="4">
  </label>
    <label class="container-select">
    <img src="https://placehold.co/600x400">
    <input type="radio" name="field" id="field-5" value="5">
  </label>
    <label class="container-select">
    <img src="https://placehold.co/600x400">
    <input type="radio" name="field" id="field-6" value="6">
  </label>
    <label class="container-select">
    <img src="https://placehold.co/600x400">
    <input type="radio" name="field" id="field-7" value="7">
  </label>
    <label class="container-select">
    <img src="https://placehold.co/600x400">
    <input type="radio" name="field" id="field-8" value="8">
  </label>
    <label class="container-select">
    <img src="https://placehold.co/600x400">
    <input type="radio" name="field" id="field-9" value="9">
  </label>
    <label class="container-select">
    <img src="https://placehold.co/600x400">
    <input type="radio" name="field" id="field-10" value="10">
  </label>
</div>

.container {
    background: black;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(10,minmax(0, 1fr));
    justify-content: space-around;
    gap: .25em;
    height: 700px;
    width: 100px;
}

input[type=radio] {
  display: none;
}

.container-select {
    padding: 0px;
    height: 1fr;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.container-select img {
    object-fit: contain;
    width: 90%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 50%;
    display: block;

    &:hover {
        opacity: 100%;
        transition: opacity 250ms;
    }
}

.container input[type=radio]:checked + label {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  opacity: 100%;
}

